# Gets reverted when calling ERC20.transfer in a contract, not reverted when transferring 0

Tags: solidity, erc-20, transferfrom, transfer

I have this code inside a contract

```
interface ERC20 {
//standard variables
  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant       returns (uint remaining);
  function approve(address _spender, uint _value) returns (bool success);
  function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint balance);
  function transfer(address _to, uint _value) returns (bool success);
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) returns (bool success);
}

...
    function multiERC20Transfer(address _token, address[] _addresses, uint[] _amounts)
      public
    {
        for(uint256 i=0;i<_addresses.length;i++){
            ERC20(_token).transfer(_addresses[i], _amounts[i]);
        }
    }
```

When I call this with `amounts` of `[1, 0]` it always gets reverted however when I do it with `[0, 0]` it succeeded.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

The contract that has this function is https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xfbdf97cdf6481f7b60b205916212f0e280a2f3d4#tokentxns

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Did you transfer tokens to multiERC20Transfer contract before calling it? Do you have a failed transaction hash?

Comment: I don’t think the funds will be transferred from that contract it should be transferred from the other contract that calls this function. Because transfer uses msg.sender

Comment: That is not correct, when ERC20.transfer is executed the sender will be multiERC20Transfer contract not the user.

Answer (score -1):

‘1’ is neither a valid hexadecimal number and not a valid Ethereum address for sure, it should be 0x0...0001.

‘0’ can be taken as a valid hexadecimal number and as a valid Ethereum address because 0, 0x0, 0x0000...000 all means the same bit configuration.

May be this is your problem.

By the way, the value of ‘0’ as amount is defined as to be mandatory accepted by the erc20 standard, so that is not a problem.

Comment: But I did try with `web3.utils.toHex(amount)`  too and it still doesn't work..

Comment: what I'm trying to do is to execute `multiERC20Transfer` from a multisig contract btw

Comment: You titled ERC20.transfer, that is another story. I assumed you were talking about ERC20.transfer(0,1) and (0,0). How can anyone understand you are talking about multiErc20Transfer?

Comment: oh really sorry about that..

Comment: The opening statement of your answer is wrong. Passing `1` for a `uint` parameter is most certainly valid, both when using web3.js v0.x and when using web3.js v1.x. Perhaps it is not valid when you use ethereumjs, but this dude hasn't specified his off-chain code, so all of this is not relevant here to begin with. Passing `1` for an `address` parameter, it is obviously wrong, but this dude has explicitly stated that he is passing `amounts [1, 0]`, not `_addresses of [1, 0]`.

Comment: The problem is most likely in the fact that the contract doesn't have an amount of 1 which it can transfer to the first input address.

Comment: No I don’t use 1 for address parameter. I use it for amounts. And the contract has enough funds.

Comment: and this is my offline code,  `const multisendTx = await contract.methods.multiERC20Transfer(USDC_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, addresses, amounts).encodeABI();`

Comment: did encodeABI messed up the uint[] parameter?

Comment: @bbnn: The contract doesn't need funds (ether) in this case. It needs to have a balance of **tokens**. And I personally think that you shouldn't downvote an answer which tries to help you.

Comment: sorry for downvoting, I tried to cancel the downvote, but it says it's locked... I tried to send some token to the contract and still the same...

Comment: do the pragma versions matter? The 2 contracts use 2 different versions 0.4.18 and 0.4.15

Comment: @bbnn: Should not matter once you've compiled and deployed.

Comment: I found another alternative multitransfer function in which needs bytes32[] parameter, 
`function multiERC20TransferTightlyPacked
    (
        ERC20 _token,
        bytes32[] _addressesAndAmounts
    ) ` do you know how to pass byte32[] using web3js?

Comment: @bbnn: `Web3.fromAscii` in v0.x, and `Web3.utils.asciiToHex` in v1.x. But it's designated for ASCII strings, so judging from the name of your function, you'll need to pack your data before passing it to either one of those functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, should I open another question for this.. I still don't understand.